# Fatfs string comparison for fno.fname

Tags: c, string, compare, sd-card, fatfs

I have an issue regarding reading the size of a file on my SD card. The sizes of these files will vary in the application, I therefore, need to get the size of the file. If I run the below code I can see the files in my directory along with their size.

What I need to do is store the size of the DATA.CSV file as a variable. 
How do I add a comparision to get the `fno.fsize` when the listing is `"data.csv`

This prints out:

````
00>  Listing directory: /00>         0  EVENTLOG.CSV   <DIR>   SYSTEM~1   183600  DATA.CSV ```
````

```
void Get_data_csv_file_size()//of the data csv
{
   if(Logging_UART_SD_CARD == true){NRF_LOG_INFO("\r\n Listing directory: /");}
    ff_result = f_opendir(&dir, "/");
    if (ff_result)
    {
        if(Logging_UART_SD_CARD == true){NRF_LOG_INFO("Directory listing failed!");}
    }
    do
    {
        ff_result = f_readdir(&dir, &fno);
        if (ff_result != FR_OK)
        {
            if(Logging_UART_SD_CARD == true){NRF_LOG_INFO("Directory read failed.");}
        }
        if (fno.fname[0])
        {
            if (fno.fattrib & AM_DIR)
            {
                if(Logging_UART_SD_CARD == true){NRF_LOG_RAW_INFO("   <DIR>   %s",(uint32_t)fno.fname);}
            }
            else
            {
                if(Logging_UART_SD_CARD == true){NRF_LOG_RAW_INFO("%9lu  %s", fno.fsize, (uint32_t)fno.fname);}

                if(strcmp((uint32_t)fno.fname, "data.csv")==0)//Convert both to a uint32_t
                {
                    Size_of_file = fno.fsize;//Set the size of the file
                    //Does not get to here
                }
            }
        }
    }
    while (fno.fname[0]);
}
```

Note this is programmed in C using a arm board. What operation do I need to do so I can get the file size?

I want something like:

```c
   if(fno.name == "data.csv")
   {
       Size_of_file = fno.fsize;//Set the size of the file
   }
```

Comment: Try a case-insensitive comparison with `stricmp()`.

Comment: Cant in my IDE / compiler

Comment: You could write your own version of `stricmp()` - it's pretty simple. Or convert  all the chars in `fno.fname` to lower case.

Comment: I don't think it is the sensitivity that is the issue. I have a warning over my line strcmp, how should I write it out? I want something like ```strcmp(fno.fname,"data.csv");```Or how do I convert fno.fname and data.csv to strings

Comment: They already are strings. No conversion/casting should be needed. (Assuming we are talking about this: [FILINFO](http://irtos.sourceforge.net/FAT32_ChaN/doc/en/sfileinfo.html)

Comment: I found a solution using snprintf yes I was using FILINFO but for some reason I could not directly compare them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution using `snprintf` neeeded to convert fno.fname to a string to compare the result.

```c
char string_test[9] = "DATA.CSV";
char name_test[9]={0};
snprintf(name_test, sizeof(name_test),"%s",(uint32_t)fno.fname);
NRF_LOG_INFO("Result is: %s",name_test); 
int result = strcmp(name_test, string_test);
if(result==0)//Convert both to a uint32_t
{
    Size_of_file = fno.fsize;//Set the size of the file
    NRF_LOG_INFO("Size of file using is: %9lu",Size_of_file);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just in case you determine using an implementation of stricmp() would be useful, here is one that I have used:

```
//case insensitive string compare
int cb_stricmp(const char *a, const char *b) 
{
     if(!a) return -1;
     if(!b) return -1;
     int ch_a = 0; 
     int ch_b = 0;

     while ( ch_a != '\0' &&ch_a == ch_b)
     {
         ch_a = (unsigned char) *a++;
         ch_b = (unsigned char) *b++;
         ch_a = tolower(toupper(ch_a));
         ch_b = tolower(toupper(ch_b));         
     }
    return ch_a - ch_b;
}
```